# C++ Linked list merge sort keeps losing nodes

Tags: sorting, c++11, singly-linked-list

I am having problems with merge sorting a linked list. For some reason, some of the nodes keep getting disconnected from the list. The main problem seems to be coming from multiple conditional jumps since lists such as `1 4 2 3` are sorted, albeit with 6 conditional jumps, while `4 2 3 1` loses all nodes except the one holding the value 4. My code is based off of the code from [tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus-program-to-implement-merge-sort-algorithm-on-linked-list).

```
class Node {
  public:
    int val;
    Node *next;
};

class Linked_list {
  private:
    unsigned int length;
    Node *head;

//desc: sorts in ascending order then merges two linked lists
//param: Node*, the lists being sorted
Node* Linked_List::merge_lists_ascend(Node* ll1, Node* ll2) { //function for merging two sorted list
   Node* newhead = NULL;
   if(ll1 == NULL)
      return ll2;
   if(ll2 == NULL)
      return ll1;
   //recursively merge the lists
   if(ll1 -> val <= ll2 -> val) {
      newhead = ll1;
      newhead -> next = merge_lists_ascend(ll1->next,ll2);
   }
   else {
      newhead = ll2;
      newhead -> next = merge_lists_ascend(ll1,ll2->next);
   }
   return newhead;
}

//desc: splits a linked list into two lists
//param: Node*, the list being split; Node**, the two lists that will be filled
//by the split list
void Linked_List::splitList(Node* start, Node** ll1, Node** ll2) {
   Node* slow = start;
   Node* fast = start -> next;
   while(fast != NULL) {
      fast = fast -> next;
      if(fast != NULL) {
          slow = slow -> next;
          fast = fast -> next;
      }
   }
   *ll1 = start;
   *ll2 = slow -> next;
   //spliting
   slow -> next = NULL;
}

//desc: recursive function that runs through the splitting, sorting and merging
//param: Node**, the starting node
Node* Linked_List::merge_sort_ascend(Node* start) {
        Node* head = start;
        Node* ll1;
        Node* ll2;
        //base case
        if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL) {
                return head;
        }
        splitList(head,&ll1,&ll2); //split the list in two halves
        //sort left and right sublists
        ll1 = merge_sort_ascend(ll1);
        ll2 = merge_sort_ascend(ll2);
        //merge two sorted list
        start = merge_lists_ascend(ll1,ll2);
        return start;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `merge_sort_ascend` recursively, you ignore its return value. That return value is important.

Comment: So how do I not ignore the return value then?

Comment: The same way you don't ignore the return value of `merge_lists_ascend`, say.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little confused. What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: You assign the return value of the function call to some variable, and then you use that variable. `merge_sort_ascend` rearranges the nodes of the list, and returns the head of the new list. But you don't record that head anywhere - you continue using the original node pointers, but those nodes are now in the middle of the rearranged list.

Comment: But I'm already returning a value with `start` and `head`. Should I be returning something different instead?

Comment: E.g. you start with the list `{4, 2}`; `ll1` points to `4` node. Then you call `merge_sort_ascend(ll1)`. It rearranges the nodes as `{2, 4}`, and returns a pointer to `2` node (which used to be in `ll1->next`, but not any longer). `ll1` still points to `4`, and `ll1->next` is now `NULL`. Node `2` is lost - you no longer have any pointers to it.

Comment: So should I be setting `ll1 = merge_lists_ascend(ll1)`?

Comment: Well, try it and see if it helps.

Comment: I updated the code in the initial question. Is that what you wanted me to do?

Comment: [Works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/c85j-U) (look at the last line of output in the bottom right pane).

Comment: I think the problem is coming from the fact that I have to use the `Linked_List` class to create my list so my code is slightly different from what you have.

Comment: Well, the code you've shown doesn't compile, so I had to massage it into a form that does. If your actual code doesn't work, the problem is somewhere in the code you haven't shown. If you would like further assistance, prepare a [mcve].

Comment: `source>:9:10: fatal error: linked_list.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: Can you see the other source windows? I don't know how to include .h files to the compiler so I made new tabs for them.

Comment: `Linked_List::merge_sort_ascend` should update `head` member. Otherwise, you have the same problem - `merge_sort_ascend` rearranges nodes in the list and returns the new head node, but that node is not stored anywhere. `head` member now points somewhere in the middle of the list.

Comment: I created a `set_head(Node*)` function and used it with the sort function, which worked. Thanks so much for your help!